# Telekinetic female alien

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm pretty sure this came out in the late 80's or early 90's. A TV movie about a female alien with telekinetic powers comes to earth. She meets a guy who helps her (naturally).

I believe she's running from someone whose chasing her. I can't remember if it's an alien hunter or just humans.

At the end she leaves Earth but the man she met has now gained telekinetic abilities.

Comment: Noooo. Don't close my question. LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the TV movie, ***[Starcrossed](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090066/)*** (1985)...?

> An alien woman is running from a deadly enemy and tries to hide on Earth where she meets a young mechanic, who helps her to get back home and to fight for the freedom of her people.

As noted in the IMDB synopsis above and the [review](https://tashasthinkings.blogspot.com/2013/04/review-starcrossed-1985.html) quoted below, the plot involves a mechanic named Joey (played by James Spader) helping a telekinetic alien named Mary (played by Belinda Bauer), who's on the run from aliens who've taken over her planet.

> Mary's an alien with alien powers (telepathy and telekinesis) and she's on the run from nasty aliens who have taken over her planet. Joey, being the upstanding guy he is, helps her and ends up on the wrong side of the bad aliens and the Feds. There is romance, there is mystical bonding and I just love it all.

As this other [review](https://www.genevievevalentine.com/2012/11/questionable-taste-theatre-starcrossed/) notes, in the end, Mary escapes Earth in a spaceship and Joey is left behind, having gained alien powers of his own. He's shown to remotely turn on a car's engine and make it drive toward him.

> She makes it to safety, launching moments before the feds show up en masse, out for a guinea pig and aware of James Spader’s new alien powers.

Comment: Yes. This was it. James Spader, god if i'd have remember he was in it i could have just looked up the stuff he'd been in. Good job. Thanks for the answer.